# Is there a way to add headers and footers to cells in a Word table?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, headers

I've got data in a table that I would like to print and cut out. However, I want to keep track of where they were in the table after I cut them. Is there a way to add a header/footer inside a cell so I can have it put "1a"/"1b"/etc. in each cell? I've got hundreds of cells of data, so if there's a way to write it as a formula (like page numbers in headers/footers for full pages), I'd really love to do that as well!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NO** there is no way for that in Word.

Not even the concept of cell address exists in Word.

Even with a macro it would be quite challenging as VBA doesn't work well with tables in Word.

Comment: Darn. What about Excel? I have the same table in Excel and I was trying to label them using custom cell formatting, but I can't get it to work. I tried `CELL; "-"; Text` but it's not accepting that.

Comment: I wanted to post that as its own question, but of course, I can only post once every 40 minutes so...

Comment: In Excel you can solve it. I think you can already ask another question. Please do so and I'll (or somebody quicker than me:)) add the answer.

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that table cells don't have footers in Word, the following code inserts hard-wired (i.e. non-updatable) cell coordinates in the bottom-right corner of each cell in the first table of a selection. CAVEAT: I've only run the code against simple non-nested tables. Also, the code does *NOT* include any error-handling, so make sure to back up your work, etc.

```vb
Sub InsertCellCoordinates()

    If Selection.Tables.count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Dim tbl As Table
    Set tbl = Selection.Tables(1)

    Dim RowCntr As Integer
    Dim CellCntr As Integer
    Dim rran As Range

    For RowCntr = 1 To tbl.Rows.count
        For CellCntr = 1 To tbl.Rows(RowCntr).Cells.count
            Set rran = tbl.Rows(RowCntr).Cells(CellCntr).Range.Characters.Last
            rran.Collapse wdCollapseStart

            rran.InsertParagraph

            rran.InsertAfter Chr(RowCntr + &H40) & "." & CellCntr

            rran.Paragraphs.Last.Format.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```